# using 2 jassor slider together in same html

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use full-width-slider.source as the first slider and below that I am trying to use slider-cluster.source in the same html page.But in slider-cluster .source slider1Options is not working neither the arrows are working nor the slider view where as slider2Options and slider3Options are working perfectly with same set of codes

```js
 
first 
===============
    var options = {
                $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                      //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);

            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                if (bodyWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
                else
                    $Jssor$.$Delay(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }

            ScaleSlider();
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);

            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        };







second
==============

I thing the jquery codes are conflicting somewhere














var jssorSlider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", slider1Options);

            var slider2Options = {
                $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,             //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: captionTransitions_childSliders,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                  //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                }
            };

            var jssorSlider2 = new $JssorSlider$("slider2_container", slider2Options);

            var bannerSlider_slideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade in R
            {$Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
            //Fade out L
            , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 }
            ];

            var slider3Options = {
                $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $DragOrientation: 0,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: bannerSlider_slideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                  //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                },

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $ActionMode: 0,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                    $DisableDrag: true                              //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
                }
            };

            var jssorSlider3 = new $JssorSlider$("slider3_container", slider3Options);

            var sliderClusterSlideshowOptions = ($Jssor$.$IsBrowserIE() && $Jssor$.$BrowserEngineVersion() < 8) ? null : {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
            };

            var slidercOptions = {
                $AutoPlay: false,                                   //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                  //Allows arrow key to navigate or not
                $SlideDuration: 800,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: sliderClusterSlideshowOptions,

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: captionTransitions,        //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                       //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2                                  //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $SpacingX: 4,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 4                                    //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                }
            };
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal example for us to play with?

Comment: you need to rename the sliders appropriately , for example if all your code points to slider 1 ...and you have two slideres named slider 1 you  will need to rename the second one to something else...this goes for all internal functions classes and id's

Comment: name are already isolated ,the first set of codes i am using in head section and the second set of codes i am using in body tags of the html page.I tried to run from the external .js files also,but the problem becomes more complicated

Comment: Oh wow, that is a lot of code for a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you sure it is as short as possible?